# Is col X functionally dependent of col y?

Tags: normalization

I am trying to understand database normalisation. I saw this example of 2 Normal form which is not 3 normal forms

```
Tournament              Year    Winner        Winner_Date_of_Birth

Indiana Invitational    1998    Al Fredrickson  21 July 1975
Cleveland Open          1999    Bob Albertson   28 September 1968
Des Moines Masters      1999    Al Fredrickson  21 July 1975
Indiana Invitational    1999    Chip Masterson  14 March 1977
```

Here the primary key is Tournament, Year. So no non primary key attribute is Functionally dependent on subset of primary, it is in 2NF.

How, acc to wikipedia, it is not in 3 NF because

```
Touranment, Year -> Winner and
Winner -> Winner_Date_Of_Birth
```

So there is a transitive property of Functional Dependency among keys. I understand this part, but what I would like to know is that, Since for our key

(Tournament,Year) there can only be one unique winner_date_of_birth, is it right to say that   ( Touranment, Year ) ->  Winner_Date_Of_Birth without using the transitive property above?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, transitive means that you can derive A -> C from A -> B and B -> C.